# PrimeNG p-dialog modal non-responsive

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am using a PrimeNG p-dialog control:

```
<p-dialog
  header="Theme Selector"
  [modal]="true"
  [visible]="someBoolean"
  [closeOnEscape]="true"
  [closable]="true">
```

We use these all over the system in a similar manner and they work fine.  This particular one sits in `app.component.html` and while it renders fine, and shows the "close" button, it is non-responsive.

Clicking the close icon does nothing, attaching events to `(onHide)` don't fire, and even if you place a button in it, the button's events don't fire.

I'm lost, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else experiences this, make sure to triple check your Angular property and event bindings.

This was due to binding `[visible]` and not `[(visible)]`.